# How to Describe table in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014-express

I am using SQLSERVER 2014 Express and I created `Employee` Table

I want to know the details Description for the `Employee` Table

> like NULL or NOT NULL and Datatypes

In Oracle we have `desc Employee` like any syntax? Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SSMS find table you need, right-click on it, choose **Script Table As...** -> **CREATE To** -> **New Query Editor Window**

That will give you creation script where you can see all details about table structure.

Another way is to use system tables:

```
USE MyDB

SELECT  c.name,
        s.name,
        c.max_length,
        c.is_nullable
FROM sys.columns c
LEFT JOIN sys.systypes s
    ON s.xusertype= c.system_type_id
WHERE object_id = object_id(N'Employees')
```

This will give you:

```
name            name        max_length  is_nullable
EmployeeID      int         4           0
LastName        nvarchar    40          0
FirstName       nvarchar    20          0
...etc
```

Or [views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx):

```
USE MyDB

SELECT  TABLE_NAME, 
        COLUMN_NAME, 
        DATA_TYPE,
        IS_NULLABLE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Employees';
```

Output:

```
TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE   IS_NULLABLE
Employees   EmployeeID  int         NO
Employees   LastName    nvarchar    NO
Employees   FirstName   nvarchar    NO
Employees   Title       nvarchar    YES
```

Note: also you can use `EXEC sp_help 'Employees'` more about this SP you can read on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

`SP_HELP` will give info on an object:

```
exec sp_help 'objectName'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
`exec sp_help 'Employee'` it outputs everything related to the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the table in ssms and press ALT+F1 keys together and able to see the full table description along dependencies on the table.